#  Adding icon on arraylist

Tags: android

i'm displaying folders from sdcard dynamically. How to add icon on `ArrayList`.

Code:

```
if(file.isDirectory())
{
    item.add(file.getName() + "/");    
}
```

I need to add icon to the left of `file.getName()`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add its path as a string... and then get the icon when displaying from specified path..